# Create Java DTO/POJOs from (Spring Data Rest) HAL Json Schema

Tags: java, json, spring-data-rest, dto, jsonschema

while I am evaluating Spring Data Rest deeper again, I see that Spring Data Rest is exposing Json Schema. I am able to browse through the entities profiles and see the related json schema.

Ok, from a (Java) client/consumer perspective I would now like to create the POJOs from that Json Schema, automatically (as I would do in a XML-Schema/SOAP based approach).

Is it possible? Am I missing something?

I would rather like to add some Maven plugin which points to the URL of the exposed schema and let it create the necessary Java POJOs.

I know jsonschema2pojo, but it works only with filesystem bases schema files.